# Explanation on this Molecular hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hamiltonian, molecules

I have a question regarding an old exam (quantum at undergraduate level) question that I never fully understood. We have a Hamiltonian

$$H= E\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
That supposedly models  a single electron in  cyclopropane molecule that we were told to assume was an equilateral triangle in geometry, I assume for symmetry purposes. The basis $H$ was given in was that each basis vector “corresponded to the electron being close to each of the carbon atoms”. A lot of the problem was to diagonalize this etc… but the first part simply was to asking us to say why this was a reasonable hamiltonian (answer is not just that its hermitian, as I learnt afterwards).

Solutions weren’t published but the lecturer told us to consider the inner products of the basis states. I don’t really know where to take that but I suspect its related to the symmetry of the molecule. So my question is, why is this a reasonable hamiltonian?

Comment: Not having done any math on this, I would ask if the basis vectors were self-adjoint after deciding it's Hermitian

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> So my question is, why is this a reasonable hamiltonian?

If you label the points of the triangle with numbers 1, 2, 3, then the points that are connected are the pairs:
$$
12\qquad (21)
$$
$$
23\qquad (32)
$$
$$
31\qquad (13)\;.
$$

If you wanted a Hamiltonian with matrix elements that represented the energy of a pair of connected points, you would have non-zero matrix elements
$$
H_{12} = H_{21}
$$
$$
H_{23} = H_{32}
$$
$$
H_{31} = H_{13}\;.
$$

And if there's no difference between any of the points (atoms), then you might as well just take all the matrix elements to be equal and to be equal to
$$
E\;,
$$
which is what your Hamiltonian says.

---

Beyond that there is not much to say. It should not be taken too literally as a good description of a three atom molecule. It is basically the "hopping model" for a very simple periodic structure (a three site model with periodic boundary conditions).

Answer (score 4):

Hfh’s answer is very good. However, I wanted to address specifically this:

> lecturer told us to consider the inner products of the basis states.

What they probably meant was the inner products squeezing the Hamiltonian. A quantitative way to find $H_{12} = H_{13} $ etc, is consider the matrix elements $$H_{12}= \langle\phi_1|H|\phi_2\rangle=\int d{\bf r} \phi_1^*({\bf r})H({\bf r}, -i\hbar {\bf \nabla}) \phi_2({\bf r}) $$

$$H_{13}=\langle\phi_1|H|\phi_3\rangle=\int d{\bf r} \phi^*_1({\bf r})H({\bf r}, -i\hbar {\bf \nabla}) \phi_3({\bf r}) $$

where ${\bf r}$ is centered at site 1. Because of symmetry these integrals are the same because $H$ will have the same value around site 2 and 3, because $\phi_2$ and $\phi_3$ will be the same function shifted by some vector ${\bf R}$, and of course $\phi_1$ will also have the same numerical value around site 2 and 3. All of these statements up to a complex phase. This all comes from the fact that the molecule is a perfect equilateral triangle and the sites are indistinguishable.

The same can be done to argue $H_{21} = H_{23}$ (consider integrals centered at site 2). The remaining equalities are true by hermiticity.

Comment: Yes, pictorially it makes sense this integrals are the same.